# responsive position of a form

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position my form box. To see where I was going I just made some inline style. It is also looking like I want on the desktop version, but when I see it on mobile version the form box is out of the picture.

If I made the Inline CSS in an external stylesheet, and made a Mediaquery, it would not be the correct way to do it, would it? For me it seems like bad practice?

```
<!-- Content -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12" style="width:25%; top: 70px; left: 1000px;">
                @Umbraco.RenderMacro("Ebook")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<div class="sign-up">
    <form id="ebog-trin-for-trin">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="name">Navn</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Navn" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="lastname">Efternavn</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Efternavn" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="email">E-mail</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="phone">Telefon</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Telefonnummer" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="company">Virksomhed</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Virksomhed" required/>
        </div>

        <input type="text" id="Channel" name="Channel" style="display: none;" />
        <input type="text" id="Campaign" name="Campaign" style="display: none;" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default active">Hent E-bogen</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you add viewport meta tag in you header?

Comment: Creating a media query is **exactly** the way I would solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example with the form floating to the right for larger screens, and showing full-width for smaller screens.

```css
.floating-form {
  background: #eee;
  float: right;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 320px;
}

@media (max-width: 479px) {
  .floating-form {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="floating-form">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="sign-up col-xs-12">
        <form id="ebog-trin-for-trin">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="name">Navn</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Navn" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="lastname">Efternavn</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Efternavn" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="email">E-mail</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="phone">Telefon</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Telefonnummer" required />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="company">Virksomhed</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Virksomhed" required/>
          </div>

          <input type="text" id="Channel" name="Channel" style="display: none;" />
          <input type="text" id="Campaign" name="Campaign" style="display: none;" />
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default active">Hent E-bogen</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The ´@Umbraco.RenderMacro("Ebook")´ is the form :)

Comment: I see. And you want the form floating on the right side of the page?

Comment: Hello Brandon. Thank you for your time. Yes I would like that the form was floating to the right.

Comment: @MadsKristensen: I updated my answer. Is that closer to what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Content -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                @Umbraco.RenderMacro("Ebook")
            </div>



<div class="sign-up col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <form id="ebog-trin-for-trin">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="name">Navn</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Navn" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="lastname">Efternavn</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Efternavn" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="email">E-mail</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="phone">Telefon</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Telefonnummer" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="company">Virksomhed</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Virksomhed" required/>
        </div>

        <input type="text" id="Channel" name="Channel" style="display: none;" />
        <input type="text" id="Campaign" name="Campaign" style="display: none;" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default active">Hent E-bogen</button>
    </form>
</div>

 </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raskarvishal7/xpnt7n7w/)

This Will Useful for you..